Does continuity on a closed set preserves Cauchy sequences?
Let $f$ be a real-valued continuous function on $D=[0,\infty)$. Does $f$ preserve Cauchy sequences, i.e., if $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy, is $\{f(x_n)\}$ Cauchy?
Since $D$ is closed, the Cauchy sequence has a limit in $D$, say $L$. Then, by Cauchy criterion, can I claim that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(L)$, and hence Cauchy?
Is my argument valid? Or are there any counterexamples to the statement above? Thanks.

This is precisely correct. Cauchy sequences in $D$ converge in $D$, and since $f$ is continuous it maps convergent sequences to convergent sequences, and all convergent sequences are Cauchy.

What is the Cauchy criterion doing there?

Your argument is valid only in complete metric spaces (where every Cauchy sequence is convergent). In general, you should not rely on the existence of a limit for Cauchy sequences. A better argument would be as follows.
Since $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy, then
$$
\forall\epsilon>0\quad,\quad \exists N\quad,\quad  m\ge N ,n\ge N\implies |x_n-x_m|<\epsilon.
$$
Furthermore, $f(x)$ is continuous. Therefore, by definition,
$$
\forall\epsilon>0\quad,\quad \exists \delta>0\quad,\quad 0<|x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon.
$$
Now, a combined argument of the previous two easily proves the demanded, without resorting to the existence of limits for Cauchy sequences.
A counterexample to the existence of limits for Cauchy sequences can be constructed by defining a Cauchy sequence over $\Bbb Q$ rather than $\Bbb R$, converging to some $L\in\Bbb Q^c$.
